# Kyocera P3155dn - Error Code F46F / Not able to Cancel Print Job

Tags: printer, network-printer, multi-function-printer

We solved the issue however I could not find anything that was even remotely useful online, so here is my contribution to the wider IT community.

Me and a coworker encountered an issue with our Kyocera P3155dn, where the printer would keep showing the error code F46F. We tried to find what it means however Kyocera does not have a very well maintained / easy to get list with error codes for each printer which explain what it means. The best we could find was [this page](https://castleink.com/blogs/printer-help/common-kyocera-error-codes) which some of the error codes that Kyocera uses.

When checking on the printer itself we noticed that one job was always listed in the Printing Job List. When we tried to remove the printjob via the Webinterface it stayed as canceling even after multiple restarts of the device + a "factory reset" via Webinterface.

The printer was added via a print-server and we selected the KPDL-Driver as it was the only driver that worked with our program which selects the paper-tray and does not work with the KX or XPS driver. Additionally I would like to mention that the printer was working fine for about a month as locally installed and about a week as a printserver printer.

We also noticed that the printer did sometimes print out the other jobs waiting after a restart and then once it was done it printed page 1 of the job and got stuck again. When unplugging the network cable, it was possible to navigate the menu, print out the usual reports etc. The last hint I got was when the PC was shut off and the printer worked fine with every other PC I tested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was easier than I thought. I opened the windows print spooler folder "C:\Windows\system32\spool\PRINTERS" checked if there were files remaining and low and behold there were about 20+ files in it.

Opened TaskManager as Admin, went to Services, turned off the spooler service, emptied the spooler folder, started the spooler service, printed some test pages, Done.

So next time if someone got a similar issue even with another printer, check if the spooler folder is really empty, even if the printer queue does not show you anything at all.

Comment: As an aside, people sometimes switch off the printer to stop a long print job. Then, when they reboot the printer, the entire job reprints. Windows realised the printer had disappeared and, logically assuming it did not print, restarts the job from the beginning.

Comment: @hdhondt that seems like a possibility, however I know the user to some extends and I am pretty sure that he does not turn of the printer to cancel a long print job as he never prints anything that is bigger than 10 pages on his printer. It is to avoid lose of other print jobs as there are other systems printing on there as well sometimes. It's hard to explain without giving too much info. I'm sorry. I just know he does not restart the printer in such a case. However I do know that it could have played as a fact if it was someone else.

Answer (score 0):

F46x errors are caused by problems rendering the file.  There is data in the image file that the printer can not compute.  I recommend converting the file  to a PDF file, then printing the PDF. In my experience this has always worked for me.  Of course, always make sure your print drivers are current, and that the printer firmware is current.  Kyocera updates both on a regular basis.

Comment: It wasn't possible in this case since it is a custom program doing the printing. Plus the file was stored in the Printer cache and kept failing. It was also already answered on how I solved the issue. :/